# Python - working with GitLab API 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: python, api, python-requests, gitlab

I am trying to make **POST** request to **GitLab** and make file with my Python code. **Url** is fine I tested it in Postman and request worked fine and made file in repo.

But when i tried to use Python it didn't work.

Python code:

```
req = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/38163703/repository/files/python_code_test", 
                data={"start_branch": "main",
                "branch": "main",
                "content": "test python",
                "commit_message": "python test"}, 
                headers = {"PRIVATE_TOKEN": "<token>"})

print(req.status_code, req.reason)
```

Error:

```
403 Forbidden
```

Comment: Does your token have access to the repository?

Comment: Yes i had, it was syntax problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supposed to be `PRIVATE-TOKEN` and not `PRIVATE_TOKEN` in data.